# Need to close a parent window only if the child window get closed in java swing

Tags: java, swing, frame

I have two radio buttons in frame1. On click on enable radio button, it will popup another frame called frame2. I want, not to close the frame1 while the frame2 is opened. But it get closed when click on the X. I used "frame1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);". Still it get closed.

```
enable.addItemListener(new ItemListener() 
{
  @Override
  public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) 
   {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub                     
    frame2.setVisible(true);
    frame1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
    }
```

Comment: Please provide an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits the problem you describe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look here:
[How can a Swing WindowListener veto JFrame closing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777146/how-can-a-swing-windowlistener-veto-jframe-closing)

What you will need to do is, in frame1 and frame2 you will need to set setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE). Then in the below code:

```
frame1.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
@Override
public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
       //check is frame 2 is open.. if it is then return without doing anything, else
       // frame1.dispose();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

There are number of methods to get the list of active window instances and verify which frame/window is visible or not.

1. Window.getOwnedWindows()
2. Window.getWindows()
3. Window.getOwnerlessWindows()
4. Frame.getFrames()

Answer (score 0):

In case you need to work with the frame2 only, you may try to use [dialogs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html). 
A brief googling discovered another [solution](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/close.html) as well.