# Java making confirming exit

Tags: java, swing, events

I have an application. I need to make this, when user click the close button, a confirmation will come ( just like javascript confirm dialog ) , 'Are you sure'? I'm using Swing visual editor in Netbeans and I'm using a listener on window closing. But I can't make it. Any help?

Comment: Please first search the forum as this has been asked and answered a gazillion times. For e.g., [how-can-a-swing-windowlistener-veto-jframe-closing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777146/how-can-a-swing-windowlistener-veto-jframe-closing). Also you say that you're using a WindowListner (the correct approach), "but I can't make it" -- but then don't show us what you've tried. Please do so, else we can't tell you what you're doing wrong.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I couldn't find the correct keywords for my query at that time. Thanks for the suggestion ...

Comment: You're welcome. Again, if after reviewing the link or similar ones and you're still stymied, then please show us your code and tell us any specifics on how it's not working such as error messages or wrong behavior.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Actually I was trying to implement the confirmation with the exit icon at top-right. If it was a button, there would be no problem. But how can I get a reference of that exit icon. That's why I didn't write any code...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this code:

```
jj4.addActionListener(new ActionListener()  // jj4-button's reference to implement exit
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
        {
            if(!jtextarea.getText().equals("") && !jtextarea.getText().equals(fileContent))
            {
                if(fileName == null)
                {
                    //this method have 3 options (1 = YES, 2 = NO, 3 = Cancel)
                    option = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"Do you want to save the changes ??");
                    if(option == 0)
                    {
                        //to save the text into file
                        saveAs();
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                    if(option == 1)
                    {
                        //to exit the program without saving
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    option = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"Do you want to save the changes ??");
                    if(option == 0)
                    {
                        save();
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                    if(option == 1)
                    {
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Don't use magic numbers! JOptionPane has defined varaiables to check for Yes, No and Cancel.