# how can i do showMessageDialog when i click exit on a JFrame

Tags: java, netbeans, jframe

i developed a simple image editor in java,
 how can i do to show a message dialog when i click exit on a JFrame to ask the user if he want to save the work?

thank's everybody

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java making confirming exit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7695064/java-making-confirming-exit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [Closing an Application](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/01/closing-an-application/) for basic information and examples.

You need to follow two basic steps:

1. Add a `WindowListener` to the frame and handle the `windowClosing(...)` event
2. Use the `setDefaultCloseOperation(...)` on the frame to allow the WindowListener to take control of the closing event.

The above link shows a simple example as well as a simple API that does both of the above steps so all you need to do is create an `Action` to handle your closing logic.

Comment: @idoc, why did you unaccept this answer? I provided you with the exact steps required to provide a confirm dialog hours before isi did. In fact isi changed his answer after he saw my answer (because his answer was NOT complete.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [`JOptionPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) showing up on a specific event. For example the [window closing event](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/windowlistener.html) in the `WindowListener`.

```
WindowListener wl = new WindowAdapter() {
     public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
          // add the option pane code here
     }
};
JFrame yourFrame = // your frame here
yourFrame.addWindowListener(wl);
```

A `JOptionPane` can be created as such:

```
final JOptionPane optionPane = new JOptionPane(
    "The only way to close this dialog is by\n"
    + "pressing one of the following buttons.\n"
    + "Do you understand?",
    JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
    JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
```

[image: some option pane with yes and no buttons]

Resulting option pane. Another alternative is to use one of the more specialized factory methods.

```
int option = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"Exit Application?");
if(option == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
    System.exit(0);
}
```

When you add a new close handler like this i would suggest to deactivate the default handler using this code:

```
yourFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
```

For more information about the `setDefaultCloseOperation` consult [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setDefaultCloseOperation%28int%29).

Hope this helps

Comment: ok thank's but i don't understand how to:

Use the setDefaultCloseOperation(...) on the frame to allow the WindowListener to take control of the closing event.