# How can I stop the closing of a Java application

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, windowlistener

I have a Java Desktop application and I would like when the user selects Exit to get a pop-up window that asks him if he wants to proceed with closing the application or not. I know how to make the window come up and read the user's response but what I need to know is how I can stop the application from closing (something like `System.close().cancel()`).

Is that possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can a Swing WindowListener veto JFrame closing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777146/how-can-a-swing-windowlistener-veto-jframe-closing)

Answer (score 7):

Yes it is possible.

After calling `setDefaultCloseOperation(DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE)`, add a [`WindowListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowListener.html) or `WindowAdapter` and in the `windowClosing(WindowEvent)` method, pop a [`JOptionPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html).

```
int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(frame, "Exit the application?");
if (result==JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
    System.exit(0);     
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a window listener. (Note: `WindowAdapter` is in the `java.awt.event` package)

```
myframe.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
        // do something
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

After setting the `setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);` to your JFrame or JDialog, add a windows listener :

```
addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent arg0) {
            int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog((Component) null, "Do u really want to exit ?!",
                    "Confirmation", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
            if (result == 0) {
                System.exit(0);
            } else {

            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

On your `JFrame`, you have to set a `defaultCloseOperation`:

```
JFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
```

Then set your pop-up's closing operation to `EXIT_ON_CLOSE`.