# Exit Query for Java program

Tags: java, exit

I would like to make my script run a "Query" method when the exit button on my JFrame is pushed. I tried it with set default close operation but that wont work obviously so what should i do? Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "Query" script. Do you have an action listener on your exit button?

Comment: I mean like i want it to have a popup window if you havent saved asking if you want to save. And im talking about like the default JFrame exit button.

Comment: You might need to post some code, default exit operation should work.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you say that setDefaultCloseOperiation would not work?  Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question, but [here is a very similar question on this site.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777146/how-can-a-swing-windowlistener-veto-jframe-closing)

See if the accepted answer is what you were wanting.

Comment: Well kind of. I want it to run a method when i hit the exit button though