# How do i display a confirmation message when the user clicks on the red cross? Java GUI

Tags: java, user-interface

I'm working on Java and I'm trying to display a confirmation message to the user when he wants to exit but I didn't know where I have to put it exactly. may you help me?

Answer (score 3):

You can stop frame from closing by default by using `WindowConstants.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE`   as peram to below API

```
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        this.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            /* (non-Javadoc)
             * @see java.awt.event.WindowAdapter#windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent)
             */
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                //Use JOptionPane. If everything goes fine 
                                //then do frame.dispose();

            }


        });
```

Comment: Sorry but could you tell me what @override mean? I've never used that character @ in **Java**

Comment: @user3102872: You will get detailed answer in this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/94411/814074

Answer (score 2):

If your exit is being done by pressing the x button on the window then you need to handle the windows events.

To get the confirmation message you need to pop up a JOptionPane.

There is a discussion of a number of ways to handle the window closing here:

[How can a Swing WindowListener veto JFrame closing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777146/how-can-a-swing-windowlistener-veto-jframe-closing)

Documentation on JOptionPane is here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html

Comment: The thing i didn't get is that: is it a method a have to create or a variable? it doesn't seem clear :\ Thank you, btw

Comment: A method. Methods do things, variables store data. (Sometimes you can effect the behavior of a Method by changing the value in a variable though).

Answer (score 1):

Add a [`WindowListner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowListener.html) to your `JFrame` and override [`windowClosing`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowListener.html#windowClosing%28java.awt.event.WindowEvent%29) method and do a pop-up with JOptionPane warning user.