# Catch ViewPart closing event?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, swt

I want to display a message before closing my view in an Eclipse plug-in.
How to catch the closing event?
Is it by using the `addListenerObject(Object listener)` method ?

```
  @Override
  public void createPartControl(Composite parent) { 

    //Catch view closing event
    this.addListenerObject(new //???

    });

  }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777146/how-can-a-swing-windowlistener-veto-jframe-closing)

Comment: @RanadipDutta That link is for Swing, this is Eclipse Plugin / SWT which is completely different.

Comment: Is it just a message you want to display or are you trying to stop the view closing as well?

Comment: I am not aware of any other except jframe and swing.

Comment: I do not want to stop the view closing. 
Just before it closes, it does some actions like displaying a message, then  it closes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`addListenerObject` is not relevant here.

You can override the `dispose` method of the view:

```
@Override
public void dispose()
{
  // TODO your code
  super.dispose();
}
```

You can also use an `IPartListener` to be told about the state changes of all parts:

```
getSite().getPage().addPartListener(new IPartListener()
  {
    @Override
    public void partOpened(final IWorkbenchPart part)
    {
    }


    @Override
    public void partDeactivated(final IWorkbenchPart part)
    {
    }


    @Override
    public void partClosed(final IWorkbenchPart part)
    {
      if (part == MyView.this) {
         // TODO Your code
      }
    }


    @Override
    public void partBroughtToTop(final IWorkbenchPart part)
    {
    }


    @Override
    public void partActivated(final IWorkbenchPart part)
    {
    }
  });
```